# Why does -[CALayer shouldRasterize] not rasterize the layer until it enters the application frame?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm sliding a layer into the screen, and I observed that it doesn't get rasterized until it enters the application frame, which heavily affects the performance of the first part of the animation. I haven't found this documented anywhere though.

Comment: Looks like an optimization to me. Nothing gets rasterized until it is really visible.

Comment: How could I override this optimization then?

Comment: Please, tell more about the layer you want to rasterize (size, opacity, shadow, is it just an image?) and why you think rasterizing it improves performance. There may be alternative ways to increase the frame rate.

Comment: Once the animation makes the layer enter the screen, the frame rate is low while it's been rasterized. If it had started rendering the layer as soon as it was added to the view hierarchy I wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: You can render your layer into a `UIImage` using `renderInContext:` in `CALayer` before starting the animation. When the animation has finished, replace the image with the layer.